# How do I stop GitHub from regenerating Jekyll site?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I created a Jekyll site and committed it to GitHub. However, as I'm using a custom plugin I'd like to turn off the auto generation Pages does as the site looks a bit different than on my localhost.

My _config.yml includes only the following:

```
server:      false
auto:        false

source:      .
destination: ./_site

markdown:    maruku
permalink:   date
```

Try as I might, I can't stop GitHub Pages from regenerating the site. There should be a big blue "Read More" just under the blockquote on the home page http://omgcarlos.com

My repo is here: https://github.com/OMGCarlos/omgcarlos.github.com/

Does Pages simply ignore the config file and regenerate it anyways?

Comment: Theoretically you have to place a `.nojekyll` file in the repository's root directory. Practically not worked when I tried it. See https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a try and letcha know what happens!

Comment: `.nojekyll` worked in that GitHub simply outputted what was in the master branch, without going into _site. Not quite what I was looking for, but thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a repository at [username].github.com, the contents of the master branch will be served at [username].github.com. If that repository is a Jekyll site, it will be generated.

To avoid the problem you have, you need to make sure that master only contains the contents of your _site/ directory. You can then keep the rest of your source in another branch (such as 'source'). Octopress does this in a nice way (http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/) but really, this is just a problem of managing your git repository - you want to be generating the _site directory from the 'source' branch, and keeping the _site

Comment: Awesome, this worked! It was a bit of a "duh" moment when I read your response. I assumed that there was a way to tell GitHub to simply look in _site. Thanks :)

Comment: (for fellow googlers) A note about "If that repository is a Jekyll site, it will be generated": The site builder is quite liberal with deciding that the content is a jekyll site. I got bitten by that, the builder changing and removing files on my static (non-jekyll) site.

Answer (score 17):

Just add a file named `.nojekyll` to your repos `gh-pages`-branch root and there will be no more autogeneration.

[Source-Link](https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages)

Comment: Works if your site is on the `master` branch as well, not just `gh-pages` branch